# Dropping all zeros in the start and end of a df column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `df` as follows:

```py
Date          Price
2020-01-01    0
2020-01-02    0
2020-01-03    0
2020-01-04    5
2020-01-05    5
2020-01-06    0
2020-01-07    5
2020-01-08    5
2020-01-09    0
2020-01-10    0
```

I want to drop all the zeroes before the first non-zero value and all the zeroes after the last non-zero value.
The resulting `df` would look like:

```
Date          Price
2020-01-04    5
2020-01-05    5
2020-01-06    0
2020-01-07    5
2020-01-08    5
```

Please do notice that the `0` value on `2020-01-06` is preserved as it has a non-zero number before and after.
How can I do this in pandas? Doing via loop seems very inefficient as I have a large `df`.

Comment: `df[df['value'].ne(0).groupby(df['group']).cumsum().gt(0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ne` + `cummax` twice; once to cutoff the 0s at the top; then reverse the DataFrame and cutoff the 0s at the bottom:

```
out = df[df['Price'].ne(0).cummax() & df['Price'][::-1].ne(0).cummax()]
```

Output:

```
         Date  Price
3  2020-01-04      5
4  2020-01-05      5
5  2020-01-06      0
6  2020-01-07      5
7  2020-01-08      5
```